# Why did the bytes stored in my dask distributed network increase in this round trip?

Tags: dask

I am using *dask distributed*.

I restart my distributed network (4 x workers), then submit a function to read text into a dask bag from a file (size, 25 Mb) in an s3 bucket and then compute the dask collection. I then gather the computed result to the local process, and finally delete this result and the associated future.

At the end of this roundtrip:
1) the bytes stored in the distributed network are approx 100 Mb higher (i.e. 4 x file size) than they were at the beginning. 
2) Also, I can see these “extra” bytes reside in just 2 of the 4 workers.

I can clear these “extra” bytes by restarting the distributed network (i.e. client.restart()), but that solution doesn't work for me "in the wild", where I expect to have this process running continuously with incoming files.

Please see below for the code. I call the execute function to start the round trip.

I have been referring to this link: http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html#clearing-data

```
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client


class TestClass:

   def __init__(self,
                client):
       self.client = client

   def execute(self,
               s3url):

       def remote_load():
           return db.read_text(s3url).compute()                           

       future = self.client.submit(func=remote_load).result()

       self.client.cancel(future)
       del future

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = Client("scheduler address")

    test = TestClass(client)

    test.execute("s3 url of my file")
```

What I expected was that the above code would result in bytes stored at the end of the round trip being the same as bytes stored at the beginning.

But after one round trip bytes stored increases by 100 Mb. After a second round trip, it increases some more (but less than by a further 100 Mb). And so on.

So, the bytes stored continues to grow.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? Or suggest a solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that some of the libraries that are being used here, like `boto3` or `s3fs` have some internal cache.

You're getting this on two machines rather than just one because you're submitting a dask job to run on one of your workers, rather than just your client.  I recommend replacing this

```
   def remote_load():
       return db.read_text(s3url).compute()                           

   future = self.client.submit(func=remote_load).result()
```

with this

```
   db.read_text(s3url).compute()
```